# How to disable anchor ads by Google Adsense Programmable Search Engine?

Tags: adsense

How to disable anchor ads by the Google Adsense Programmable Search Engine that show at the bottom of mobile screens?

I have created an Adsense search block which I host at 1 page of my site. I have disabled anchor ads in my Adsense site settings and they are not showing anywhere.

But the page that hosts my search form by Adsense (Google site search) shows a very small anchor ad at the bottom of the screen on mobile devices. I have only seen it with the Chrome browser for iOS, I have not seen it in Safari. It shows a prefilled search request that cannot be changed, in the example screenshots below for Apple TV.

I have reviewed all customization options in the "Programmable Search control panel" but cannot find anything. Please advise: (how) can I disable this add?

[image: the small anchor ad at my search page]

[image: this modal is shown when the anchor ad is clicked, the search term cannot be changed, only ads can be clicked]

Thanks in advance!